# ошибка после загрузки на сервер laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/virtwww/w_igovnokoder-ru_d1c3537d/http/index.php on line 50

Comment: пользуйтесь композером, и не будет подобных ошибок: в консоли надо зайти в папку с будущим проектом, и выполнить команду `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel ./ "5.5.*"`

Comment: а что сейчас та мне делать? уже с созданным)что сделать чтобы все работало ?

Comment: переустановить с помощью композера, но сначала надо удалить всё из директории.

Comment: Привыкайте не только спрашивать "что мне сейчас делать", но и "как в будущем избежать подобных ошибок"? Например, вам помог бы Git - посмотреть, какие изменения были с момента последней работающей версии файла. </НравоученияOff>

Answer (score 1):

Проверь файл index.php и конкретно 50 строку - видимо при копировании или до копирования туда попал либо шумовой символ, либо не закрыта скобочка `}`